# sf package read shapefile for st_within

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf, r-sp

I'm trying to use st_within to find points within a polygon, but I can't get a shapefile into the right format. I'm using the standard shp file JPN_adm1.shp from https://purl.stanford.edu/np872wp5062 or https://gadm.org/download_country.html

```r
JPN <- st_read("JPN_adm1.shp")
JPN <- JPN[1,] ## select one prefecture, Aichi
JPN <- st_transform(JPN, crs="WGS84")

tokyo.df <- data.frame("name"="Tokyo","lat"=35.507,"lon"=139.208)
some_point.sf <- st_as_sf(tokyo.df, coords = c("lon","lat"), crs="WGS84")
some_point.sf <- st_transform(some_point.sf, crs="WGS84")
subset <- st_join(some_point.sf, JPN, join = st_within)
```

The code runs, but it doesn't exclude Tokyo which isn't in Aichi. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not need to use the lines of code starting with `st_transform()` because the `JPN` and `some_point.sf` objects are already in `WGS84`

Secondly, not sure to fully understand your problem, but I give it a try! I guess you just need to set the argument `left = FALSE` inside the `st_join()` function. Otherwise `st_join()` performs a `left join` by default (instead of a `inner join` which is required in your specific case).

Please find below a reprex:

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(sf)

JPN <- st_read("JPN_adm1.shp")
JPN <- JPN[1,] ## select one prefecture, Aichi
# JPN <- st_transform(JPN, crs="WGS84")            # NO NEED TO DO THAT

tokyo.df <- data.frame("name"="Tokyo","lat"=35.507,"lon"=139.208)
some_point.sf <- st_as_sf(tokyo.df, coords = c("lon","lat"), crs="WGS84")
# some_point.sf <- st_transform(some_point.sf, crs="WGS84")       # NO NEED TO DO THAT
subset <- st_join(some_point.sf, JPN, join = st_within, left = FALSE) # ADD ARGUMENT "LEFT = FALSE"
```

- Output

You get an empty `sf` object as expected:

```
subset
#> Simple feature collection with 0 features and 13 fields
#> Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>  [1] name      ID_0      ISO       NAME_0    ID_1      NAME_1    HASC_1   
#>  [8] CCN_1     CCA_1     TYPE_1    ENGTYPE_1 NL_NAME_1 VARNAME_1 geometry 
#> <0 lignes> (ou 'row.names' de longueur nulle)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>